# FileNotFoundException dfs.include - Hortonworks for windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I tried to install Hortonworks 2.2.0.2.0.6.0-0009 for Windows on a Windows Server 2012.
Everything seems clean during the installation except when launching "start_local_hdp_services.cmd" to start hadoop services. There, namenode and historyserver services fail to start and generate folowing logs :

For "hadoop-namenode-M1BY1HADOOP.log" :

```
2014-03-06 09:39:06,755 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.HostFileManager: failed to read include file 'c:\hdp\hadoop-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-0009/etc/hadoop/dfs.include'. Continuing to use previous include list.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: c:\hdp\hadoop-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-0009\etc\hadoop\dfs.include (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.HostsFileReader.readFileToSet(HostsFileReader.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.HostFileManager$MutableEntrySet.readFile(HostFileManager.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.HostFileManager.refresh(HostFileManager.java:284)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.<init>(DatanodeManager.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.java:237)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:609)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:567)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:443)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:491)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:684)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:669)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1254)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
```

For "hadoop-historyserver-M1BY1HADOOP.log":

```
014-03-06 09:39:20,130 INFO org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://VMHADOOP:8020/mapred/history/done]
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: Error creating done directory: [hdfs://VMHADOOP:8020/mapred/history/done]
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.HistoryFileManager.serviceInit(HistoryFileManager.java:503)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistory.serviceInit(JobHistory.java:88)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.CompositeService.serviceInit(CompositeService.java:108)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.serviceInit(JobHistoryServer.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.launchJobHistoryServer(JobHistoryServer.java:155)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.hs.JobHistoryServer.main(JobHistoryServer.java:165)
```

Does anybody know the reason of this error and can help me to solve it please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in hadoop (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-2355), create empty dfs.include and dfs.exclude file and the problem would vanish.